# Use single Azure SQL database to host different environment database version

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure

**Given**
4 databases hosted in Azure SQL, where 1st is production database, 2nd database for qa site, 3rd for staging slot and 4th for automation acceptance tests

**Task**
Optimize costs by reducing quantity of paid azure sql databases

Application which consume database uses EF 6 and initial idea to solve this task was about using schema per environment and keep all tables in single database, database table and data changes would be independent.

**Example**

- qa.Account
- slot.Account
- aat.Account
- qa.Feedback
- slot.Feedback
  and so on

**Question**
Did anybody implement such approach and what is potential drawbacks by holding tables for different environments in single database?

Off course except production.

Comment: If your volumes are low, then managing a schema per environment makes sense. What may be challenging is managing any IAC code / DacPacs, since you will have to intercept and interfere with the schema, or manage multiple copies of your artefacts, the latter sounds like a recipe for pain.

Answer (score 1):

> Does anybody implemented such approach and what is potential drawbacks by holding tables for different environments in single database?

There is absolutely no reason to do that.  If your goal is to:

> Optimize costs by reducing quantity of paid azure sql databases

Simply switch your databases over into an [Elastic Pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-pool).  Elastic Pools cost the same as single databases, under both DTU or vCore pricing.

Comment: Actually the goal is to reduce quantity of databases

Comment: Why is that a goal?  It increases complexity, reduces security, reduces capabilities, and does not decrease costs.

Comment: Reduce amount of databases and $. As an example: database for automation tests required only for 1 hour per day and no any reason to pay for 23 hour of no usage.

Comment: How does your proposed solution help with that?

Comment: I can split tables by different schema and use single database for two or more environments

Comment: Or, for the same cost, you can have two separate databases in the same Elastic Pool.  You don't save any money by cramming more data into a single database.